# How to share a text to mail in Window Store App?

Tags: c#, api, windows-store-apps

I want to share a text via mail in windows store app. Can anyone please suggest me a coding?

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Unfortunately, it's not clear what you want to achieve or what you have tried so far.

Comment: With due respect please remove negative remarks i.e NEGATIVE VOTE, I've answered what I want. I would be very grateful to you if u please remove your negative remarks :).

Comment: @MohammadHani, it's not kindergarten. There are stackOverflow rules, on this website, you have to guide them if you value time of other people, and want to get meaningful answer. Thanks for the understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public softDrinkProductDet()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataTransferManager dfm = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
        dfm.DataRequested += dfm_DataRequested;
    }

    void dfm_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        DataRequest dr = args.Request;
        dr.Data.Properties.Title = "Your Title";
        dr.Data.Properties.Description = "Description";

        dr.Data.SetText("Some Shareing");
    } 
    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
    }
```

**Thanks & Regards,**